# error: snap "rocketchat-server" not found

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, vps, ubuntu-server, rocket.chat

I'm trying to install rocketchat-server, but it seems I can't make it work on my VPS.

I've installed snap just fine. Now that I try to hint the command line :

```
sudo snap install rocketchat-server
```

I get the following error message :

```
error: snap "rocketchat-server" not found
```

Going through the web, nobody seems to get that error, so I'm a little confused as to what to do next. I was supposed to get a functionnal RocketChat Server within 30 seconds, but it's been hours and I can't seem to understand what is wrong.

What I'm trygin to accomplish :

- install RocketChat on my VPS
- my VPS is on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- if I run uname -i I get aarch64, sooo I'm guessing I have a 64 bits OS ? (the
  docs say 32 bit is not supported)
- by the way I'm testing rocketchat on a Scaleway server (a friend told me that it could be the problem, but well, i'm not knowledgeable enough)

Thank you for your answers (and sorry for my non native english)

Comment: I have the same problem on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: maybe more adapted on serverFault since it isn't a question on programmation

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to your problem.
(https://websetnet.net/de/why-do-you-see-error-snap-xyz-not-found/)
Try to install snapd

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

Then install with snap rocket.chat

```
sudo snap install rocketchat server
```

The problem is that the snap package on Ubuntu doesn't have anything to do with snapd. 
(https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/146#issuecomment-298157614)